# Meta programming into several output languages

Tags: php, javascript, c++, metaprogramming

I'm looking for a way to have to write and maintain a certain algorithm (a graphics rendering sub-module of my code, actually) only once. I need the algorithm in C++, PHP and Javascript. Theoretically I could write it in C++ and wrap it into a PHP extension; but that has many issues of itself and doesn't solve the Javascript link.

What I'm looking for, I  think, is a tool that converts from a language (doesn't matter which one) into the three (or two, if the source language is one of the three) output languages I'm targetting. I've found MetaL (http://www.meta-language.net/) which seems to do what I want but also looks dead (no updates since 2007) and only targets one of the three languages I need. It needs to be quite flexible and allow me to update the results - for example, I use Cairo in my C++ and PHP rendering, and HTML Canvas on the Javascript side. So I need to customize to the API for certain effects.

Alternatively, I'd settle for a PHP parser and lexer that would give me an AST with enough information for me to write generators for C++ and Javascript as an alternative backend.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Your question reminded me of the old quote: _Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems._

I understand your will to centralize maintenance, but it sounds to me like you're taking a somewhat-annoying-but-reasonable problem and turning it into a VERY complicated problem. (I am thinking of the automated build, the problems with the translation engine, and the debugging hell you're about to enter)

Think of the poor guy who has to maintain this solution after you've moved on..

Comment: If you are talking about at most a few thousand lines of code, you'd be better off to design the API carefully and simply recode them.  Automated code generation for all the odd things one finds in a langauge (e.g., for C++: classes, multiple-inheritances, namespaces, seperate declaration/definition, macros, templates, overloads, ...) is a big task and isn't worth the effort for a few thousand lines.  If you want to generate 100K SLOC it would be well worth the effort, or if you composed code fragments in arbitrary ways.   But 3 copies of a fixed algorithm? Don't think its worth the trouble.

Comment: I can afford to restrict myself to a much smaller subset of a language to write this in. I obviously don't need to translate all nuances of C++ into several languages. The rendering is 90% 'calculate location of pixel, rectangle or circle, calculate color of it, call drawing API function'. It doesn't have to be general purpose. Anyway it looks like haXe will do what I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take a look at [Haxe](http://haxe.org/). Haxe is an open source programming language. It can be compiled to JavaScript, Flash/ActionScript, PHP, C++, Java, C#, Python and Lua.

Comment: Aha very good, thank you, I hadn't found that in my googling.

Answer (score 2):

The Emscripten project (which I only spotted last week) might interest you: http://syntensity.blogspot.com/2011/04/emscripten-10.html

This guy has basically written a compiler for C/C++ that compiles to Javascript code.

That should solve the Javascript side of your problem.

Hope that helps.

Another product along the same lines, and a bit more well known is Google Web Toolkit (GWT). It's based on Java, but the end result is similar -- you write your web application in Java code and it compiles the front-end parts into Javascript and the back-end parts into regular Java bytecode. I know you're not asking for Java, but if it interest you, the link is here: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/

Slightly less useful, but possibly more relevant to your question is [PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/). This is a project to implement as much of the PHP language in Javascript as possible. They're doing it on a function-by-function basis, so it's only ever going to be an approximation, but given that the language syntaxes are similar, it may be possible to use it to write code that works unchanged in native PHP and also in Javascript on the client side.

Of course the one big down-side of compiling one language into another is that the resulting code is always going to be sub-optimal. There's not much you can do about that, but it's worth bearing in mind before you start down the path of writing a shared code-base in a single language.

Comment: Thanks, Emscripten looks very relevant. I guess if it has a javascript backend, a PHP backend shouldn't be all that hard - especially since I only need a very limited subset of language constructs.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe look into 'coding' your original algorithm in xml and using various xslt templates to output to your target languages ? Or possibly antlr (http://www.antlr.org/ [http://www.amazon.com/Definitive-Antlr-Reference-Domain-Specific-Programmers/dp/0978739256/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1303114884&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0978739256)).

Comment: Yeah that's more or less what MetaL tried to do I think, just without the xslt from what I can tell. I haven't had many good experiences with xslt, so I'm going to skip that, but maybe I can make some easy other xml->code transforms... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can just Write it in javascript and then use a C++ and PHP javascript interpreter.

Comment: @Roel: "Rendering" is usually computationally intense.  Building a layer of interpreters to do this in face of a computationally intense task doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Comment: In my case it doesn't matter. It's worth the trade off.

Answer (score -1):

A completely different approach would be to use assembly code. Write the algorithm in a language of your choice, compile it to ASM source. Then provide the interface wrappers in the deployment languages.

Of course this is all so much 'air pie'. It depends upon so many variables, number of target platforms, importance of optimization,  frequency of interface change related to implementation change etc etc